# TRIM of ssd behind raid controller

Tags: ssd, trim

I have nfs storage with many SSDs in raid controller, for my cluster of 10 linux machines,

I've used it for around 3 years, and now about 83% is used.(43T out of 55T)

I haven't done any kind of TRIM yet.

Do I need TRIM? (or similar optimization)

How do I check if TRIM will help or not for performance?

Comment: Probably yes, and probably you can not, and probably it is the fault of the raid controller. Use sw raid. If you can not throw it out, then a full backup and a from-zero recover will help.